# Ffmpeg Can Not Open "display"

Tags: ffmpeg

I get this error when I type in the terminal:

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -y -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -vcodec huffyuv out.avi`

I am using Ubuntu 21.10, and after typing into the terminal `echo DISPLAY`, I get "a :1"

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. You can [edit] your question. If you get `:1` so why use `0:0`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -y -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i $DISPLAY -vcodec huffyuv out.avi
```

You display is not `:0.0`.